# Is there a way to use np.where() with column list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I try to create **new variable** with np.where() function.

```
myDF['newVar'] = np.where((myDF['var1']==1) |
                           (myDF['var2']==1) |
                           (myDF['var3']==1) ,
                           1, 0)
```

Is there a way to replace var1, var2, var3 by a list like this *(same condition ==1 for each column)*:

```
listVars=['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
myDF['newVar'] = np.where((myDF[listVars]==1),
                           1, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with `axis=1`:

```
listVars=['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
myDF['newVar'] = np.where((myDF[listVars]==1).any(axis=1), 1, 0)
```

For example:

```
myDF = pd.DataFrame({
    "var1": [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    "var2": [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    "var3": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
})

listVars=['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
myDF['newVar'] = np.where((myDF[listVars]==1).any(1),1, 0)

print(myDF)
#   var1  var2  var3  newVar
#0     1     1     0       1
#1     1     0     0       1
#2     1     1     0       1
#3     0     0     0       0
#4     0     1     0       1
```